# Unable to update a value of a hash

Tags: elixir

I have a struct which has a nested key with another list of structs and I want to update that nested key values with new values.

```
source = get_data 

# source.key1 is an array of structs

source.key1 = Enum.each(source.key1, fn(x) -> # error is here at "="
  # ...
end)
```

The error is:

```
cannot invoke remote function source.key1/0 inside match
```

neither this:

```
aa = Enum.each(source.key1, fn(x) ->
  # ...
end)

source.key1 = aa # error is here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a map, which looks like this:

```
my_map = %{a: "a", "b" => b}
```

You can access it with:

my_map.a for get "a" 
   my_map[:a] for get "a"
   my_map["b"] for get "b"

You can't apply `atom` syntax for key, which isn't an atom.

To update the map you should use two functions:

```
Map.put(my_map, "new_key", "new_value")
or
Map.update(my_map, "new_key", "init value", fn for add values) # handy in recursion loop
```

There's also `Map.update!/3`, but it will raise `KeyError` if key is not in the map.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a map with `source.key1 = ...`

The error you are seeing is as a result of trying to call a function during pattern matching.

To update a map you can either do:

```
%{source | key1: aa}
```

This will raise if `key1` does not already exist in the map.

Or:

```
Map.put(source, :key1, aa)
```

This will not raise if `key1` does not already exist in the map.

---

You should also note that the result of `Enum.each` is the atom `:ok` so this will set `key1` to `:ok`.

Perhaps you want an [Enum.map/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2)?

You should also check out [update_in/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3)